Grid-level spatial fixed effects (with time and seasonality)
I have panel data with reported human-wildlife conflicts with a date and grid cell location:

I'm trying to isolate the impact that extreme precipitation and temperature have on conflict rates. I am thinking of using grid cell and month-year fixed effects.
Will controlling for these eliminate most heterogeneity, or should I include other control variables? Is there anything to look out for with spatial autocorrelation? These obviously have large amounts of seasonality—how should that be weighed against month-year fixed effects? How do I craft the best causal identification strategy?
